# Rails create database entry by GET?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, get, request

is it possible to create a database entry (create method) by a GET request instead of POST?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, just send the necessary params using link_to for instance

Comment: the thing is: i have to use a php proxy for ajax request which actually does only send GET requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now I have some more details, here is some answer. If you'll receive this kind of request:

```
your_route?price=123&name=abc
```

Make a route like:

```
match 'your_route/:price/:name' => 'your_controller#your_method'
```

If ever you've optional params, use brackets.

in your controller, you'll get the params. Given you have a `Product` model with columns `price` and `name`, proceed as follows to save it:

```
@product = Product.new({:price => params[:price]), :name => params[:name]})
@product.save
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do in response to a GET request is entirely up to you. Of course, multiple GET requests with the same parameters could potentially create multiple records, which might not be what you want. Browsers will resend GET requests but will normally prompt the user to resent POST requests.